# Netty Client sending Keep Alive HTTP request

Tags: http, netty, client-side, keep-alive

I am creating a Netty Client which sends HTTP request to POST data to server.To increase the performance what i did was using Keep alive Http request(i know that in HTTP 1.1 all requests are keep alive by default, so i am making sure that Connection header is not set to close while sending the Http request) so that it uses the same channel to send the Http Request. Now when i send the Http request to the correct URL,i.e. if i get HttpResponse Status OK in return from server, i am able to send the next Http Request properly but when i send the Http Request for which i get BAD REQUEST or  SERVICE UNAVAILABLE or something other than OK then i am unable to send the next request that is the channel future f.success() returned after calling channel.write(request) is false. I am unable to understand why it happens. [I have followed the same model of coding as done in HttpSnoopClient example given in netty,](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopClient.java)
except i have removed the connection:close header & even the client handler is the same as that given in snoop client, also i have am instantiating the bootstrap only once at the starting
I tried getting channelFuture f.cause().getMessage() but it was null it seems